# Buenas, como le hago para poblar una tabla con 10mil tuplas, con campos donde existe texto, como nombre o Direccion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Por ejemplo tengo la tabla boleto con Carnet de Identidad, hora, fecha y numero de vuelo, cómo puedo hacer para llenarla completa, a través de que metodo o de que forma, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Buscando en internet probé la que viene con esta sentencia

```
COPY nombre_delatabla FROM 'C:\laubicacion\delarchivo\Libro1.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

En este caso al `nombre_delatabla` le ingresé los datos que tenía en un archivo en el disco al que le llamé `libro1.csv` con 10 registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado fue este después de hacer el `SELECT * FROM nombre_delatabla`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo que añadir que pude hacerlo desde una ubicación pública, por si te sale error entonces tendrías que modificar los permisos de ese archivo.

Comment: ¡Ya tienes suficiente reputación como para comentar! Esta es la zona de respuestas.

Comment: Tienen que ser registros reales!

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres poblar con datos que sean reales? ¿Te refieres a restaurar un backup? Si quieres generar datos falsos que parezcan reales puedes generar un pequeño script en php y utilizar la librería [faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) o buscar alguna similar para tu lenguaje deseado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me funcionó por el segundo metodo a traves de un backup!